# Sobrepor imageviews

Tags: java, android

Eu quero fazer um layout com imagens sobrepostas dessa forma
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas eu não consigo sobrepor as imagens dentro de uma mesma activity ou fragment
alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Eu acredito que não dá pra colocar duas imagens em um **ImageView**, mas você pode criar duas **ImageViews** e colocar uma em cima da outra. Use um **FrameLayout** ou um **RelativeLayout**.

Comment: não é dentro do mesmo imageview, até porque pretendo usar um listener para cada imagem, to vendo a possibilidade do framelayout

Comment: Então provavelmente você ta usando LinearLayout. Com o FrameLayout vai Funcionar se quiser entender como ele funciona, sugiro esse video: http://www.thiengo.com.br/entendendo-e-utilizando-framelayout-no-android

Comment: Porque você não cria 3 imagens, mudando só o botão aberto? Ai deixa sempre duas invisiveis, e uma visivel.

Comment: por que eu precisa de chamadas de eventos em separado para cada uma, mas eu já consegui se quiserem saber como se faz é so perguntar